# Login one WordPress site user to other WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

We have two sites developed in WordPress. One is a membership site and the other is a journal. Now I want to log in to the membership site's user to the Journal site without creating the account in Journal. Is this possible in Wordpress to login a user from one site to other Wordpress site without creating account in second site?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, you will need to integrate the database. Both projects will need to access or consume a single source of information (database or web service, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but both databases are hosted on different server. Sites are not sharing same databases. For now, I have developed a plugin using oauth servie that allow second site's user to login using the credentials on first site (Membership site where users are existing) , but this sso plugin creates the same user in the second site. I don't want to recreate the same users. Can we login the user without creating account in the second site?